# Preamble problem

Tags: spacing, preamble, subsection

[image]unfortunately, I don't have any minimal working example to show how the problem is wrong. But, I have the following preamble, and there is some spacing that is occurring above and below my section titles and I am not able to use vspace to alter the spacing. I can only post the preamble, in hope that someone catches some mistake sometime soon.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{latexsym,booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[singlespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref} %% to make the referencing clickable 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{skip=6pt}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{array, makecell}

%% to change the title of the chapters 
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\Large}{\thechapter}{1em}{} \vspace{6pt}]
\titlespacing\subsubsection{-5pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{-5pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

% Referencing packages 
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}

%% Copied from repository before to make make comments

\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\tb}[1]{\noindent \textcolor{NavyBlue}{\textbf{Tom:}  #1}} % 1 'cause Trom is the best! 
\newcommand{\ish}[1]{\noindent \textcolor{Orange}{\textbf{Ish:}  #1}}


%% For modeling
\usepackage{optidef}

\geometry{a4paper,left=2cm,right=2.0cm, top=2cm, bottom=2.0cm}

\newtheorem{Definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{Lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{Corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{Proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{Algorithm}{Algorithm}
\numberwithin{Theorem}{section}
\numberwithin{Definition}{section}
\numberwithin{Lemma}{section}
\numberwithin{Algorithm}{section}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}


% *********************************************************************
% Headings and page layout
% *********************************************************************
%\usepackage{fancyhdr} % to design my own headings
%\usepackage{titlesec, titletoc} % to design my own toc and part/chapter/section styles

% page style of "chapter"
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\LARGE \bfseries}
    {\Large Chapter \thesection \thispagestyle{plain}}{0ex}{\titlerule\vspace{2ex}}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0ex}{-8ex}{8ex}

%\titleformat{\section}[display]{\LARGE \bfseries}
%   {\Large Section \thesection \thispagestyle{plain}}{0ex}{\titlerule\vspace{2ex}}
%\titlespacing*{\section}{0ex}{-8ex}{8ex}


% definition of headings
\fancypagestyle{memo}{
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
    \fancyhead[RE]{\rightmark}
    \fancyhead[LO]{\leftmark}
    \renewcommand\headrulewidth{0.5pt}
}


\section{Clustering} \label{sec:clustering}

All new hurriances in the city blasting away the air and water
\subsection{Choice of clustering} \label{subsec:choice_of_clustering}
cluster cluster where are you? 

\subsection{Validity of clusters} \label{subsec:validity_of_clusters}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have added a photo, apologies, I am not able to produce a minimal sample with this.

Comment: Note the article class has no chapters.

Comment: Alright I will add it

Comment: Done, I have added as you suggested

Comment: What happens when you compile the the code you just posted?

Comment: I dont know, the their is a huge gap between sections and subsections and no gap between subsections and the text. I have even tried to introduce \vspace{} to increase or decrease space but all in vain.

Comment: You need to check that the code you post is an example of the problem you are asking about.. If I try the code posted I get `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.` and no output. You need to post the code that generates the image that shows the problem,. Posting unrelated code does not help anyone to help you.

Comment: To make your code compilable, it's necessary to load the `fancyhdr` package, remove the `titlesec`-related stuff (I have to do so as the `article` document class doesn't recognize the `\chapter` command), remove a stray `]` closing square bracket symbol, and add a `\begin{document}` instruction in the appropriate place. Once I make these adjustments/corrections, the spacing below the `section`-level header and around the `subsection`-level headers looks just fine. In other words, the code you've provided doesn't generate the issue you say you wish to correct.

Comment: @Mico I cannot find this stray ], can you guide me to where it is. Stress speaking, sorry.

Comment: @Jimjamlorde -- Do you see the line that starts with `\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\Large}{\thechapter}{1em}{} \vspace{6pt}`? What's at the very end of that line?

Comment: Was your problem solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know, what you try here, but it looks a bit like a misuse. Nevertheless, I will try an answer as best as I can.

In general:
If you want to find the error in general, make a copy delete everything between begin and end-document. Then check, if the error still appears. If it does (likely it will), comment out your whole preamble and uncomment step by step, until the error appears. Over all, all vspace is gathered inside a paragraph and added at the end of a paragraph. So, if you have your code looks like this:

```
\vspace*{-10pt}
\section{tigglywiggly}
```

It won't work, as there is no new paragraph. You can see this behaviour in the following code.

```
\documentclass[a4, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1] A paragraph \vspace{-3pt} is \vspace{20pt} going \vspace{-8pt} to end.

\lipsum[1] This paragraph is also \vspace{9pt} finished now.

\lipsum[1] This paragraph has \vspace{20pt} 20pt.

\lipsum[1] This paragraph is is without vspace.

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

The first two paragraph breaks are the same size, as the sum of both vspaces added up i 9pt.

If you want to force vertical space to appear, you can use vskip:

```
\documentclass[a4, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1] A paragraph \vskip -3pt\relax is \vskip 20pt\relax going \vskip -8pt\relax to end.

\lipsum[1] This paragraph is also \vskip 9pt\relax finished now.

\lipsum[1] This paragraph has \vskip 20pt\relax 20pt.

\lipsum[1] This paragraph is is without vspace.

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

As you see, `\vskip` breaks the text into paragraphs. Sometimes it is suppressed, i.e. at page begin. If you want to force it, you need to put null in before, after or both: `\null\vskip 30pt\relax\null`

`\relax` does nothing. It indicates that `\vskip` is finished here. Use it with commands like `\vskip`. Otherwise you get side effects.
`\null` is a empty box, which behaves like a printable character.