# Chapter not coming at all

Tags: chapters, titlesec

I am facing this problem that the chapter name is not appearing at all. Though, the title names for section and subsection are appearing. I'm attaching my minimal working code with this question, in hope someone could help me understand what is wrong.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{latexsym,booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[singlespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{skip=1pt}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Referencing for Trom 
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}


\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\tb}[1]{\noindent \textcolor{NavyBlue}{\textbf{Tom:}  #1}} 
% 1 'cause Trom is the best! 
\newcommand{\ish}[1]{\noindent \textcolor{Orange}{\textbf{Ishaan:}  #1}}


%% For modeling
\usepackage{optidef} % Ugly package, remove this package later. 

\geometry{a4paper,left=2cm,right=2.0cm, top=2cm, bottom=2.0cm}

\newtheorem{Definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{Lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{Corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{Proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{Algorithm}{Algorithm}
\numberwithin{Theorem}{section}
\numberwithin{Definition}{section}
\numberwithin{Lemma}{section}
\numberwithin{Algorithm}{section}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

% Remove the spaces from above , and beneat align, though these need to be edited. 
%\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\newcommand{\zerodisplayskips}{%
%  \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{4pt}%
%  \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{4pt}%
%  \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{4pt}%
%  \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{4pt}}
%\appto{\normalsize}{\zerodisplayskips}



% *********************************************************************
% Headings , and page layout
% *********************************************************************
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % to design my own headings
\usepackage{titlesec, titletoc} % to design my own toc , and part/chapter/section styles

% page style of "chapter"
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\LARGE \bfseries}
   {\Large Chapter \thispagestyle{plain}}{0ex}{\titlerule\vspace{2ex} }
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0ex}{-2ex}{2ex}

\fancypagestyle{memo}{
   \pagestyle{fancy}
   \fancyhf{}
   \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
   \fancyhead[RE]{\rightmark}
   \fancyhead[LO]{\leftmark}
   \renewcommand\headrulewidth{0.5pt}
}



\begin{document}
\chapter{abc}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `article` class does not have chapters. use `report` to have `\chapter`

Comment: There are no chapters in the `article` class. If you need those, use either `report` or `book`.

Comment: you were told in your last question that article does not define `\chapter`  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/609883/preamble-problem#comment1525661_609883

Comment: Cool thanks for reminding me! Stresss!